# Hybrid Database: Is it okay to store MongoDB ids in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design

I'm designing a database schema for **Movie Recommendation System** using Hybrid Database. For this, I'm using popular MySQL and MongoDB.

Application has two types of data, one is user action data and the other is unstructured movie data.

```
# MySQL Tables
1. User
2. User_Movie_Like
3. User_Movie_Watchlist
4. User_Movie_Recommendation

# MongoDB Collections
1. Movie
```

To achieve **easy lookup** for movies, I've created a dictionary table in MySQL consisting of MongoDB's ObjectIds. In this dictionary table, I'm storing objectId of mongo document and movie name.

```
# MySQL Tables
5.Movie_Master
| id - Primary Key
| objectId - MongoDB's reference
| name - duplicate from movie collection
```

Is this the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about "recommended" - but it's worth outlining benefits and drawbacks.

The benefit of your solution is that it allows you to model most of your domain in your database, and apply referential integrity - table `user_movie_like` can have a foreign key to table `movie`, and you can avoid bugs like "we deleted a movie, but forgot to delete all the likes". I would imagine that for certain actions, caching the movie name in MySQL will avoid going to MongoDB to retrieve the name, and thus speed up your application.

By using MongoDB for unstructured data, you can deal with not knowing the schema in advance.

The drawbacks are that you're using two separate data stores for your application - you could, for instance, store the unstructured movie data in JSON objects in MySQL and avoid the two sets of queries.

Another drawback is that by caching movie name in MySQL, you introduce opportunities for bugs - if you update the movie name in MongoDB, but not in MySQL, your application may behave oddly.

Another drawback is that there's no built-in mechanism to guarantee referential integrity across the two data stores - you can delete a movie in MongoDB, but not in MySQL.